# How to find lines with a single character different

Tags: regex

Example text file:

```
\folder_0
\folder-0
\folder-1
\folder'2
\folder-3
\folder_3
\folder'3
\folder,3
\folder,4
```

How do you find the the lines that are the same bar one character. Eg:

```
\folder_0
\folder-0
\folder-3
\folder_3
\folder'3
\folder,3
```

Comment: With which tool or language? Also, do those lines have to be consecutive? Lastly, what have you tried?

Comment: `\folder-0` and `\folder_3` differ by two characters, so how can they be in the same result set?

Comment: @hochl I think he doesn't mean pairwise, but just consecutive ones or so.

Comment: Then why is `\folder,4` not part of the set? `\folder,3` is a member and the difference is just one. The problem isn't explained very well.

Comment: You're right, that should have been in the set. I've edited the question. I could have added more background detail but I've gotten criticised for making questions to specific. In my real world case they do crop up in pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions.

Start by defining a function that given two strings (lines from the file) returns true they only differ by a single character.

Then use an associative array to collect groups of lines that only differ by a single character based on that function.

After processing the file, any entries in the associative array that contain multiple lines are the results you want.

Comment: Thanks, Once I knew I wasn't reinventing the wheel I wrote a script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible way how to... (in Perl)...

```
@m = (m/[\s\S]*?(?:^|\n)(?=(.*?)(.)(.*?)(?:\n|$)(?:[\s\S]*?\n|)(\1.\3)(?:\n|$))/g);
@p = ();
while ($#m > 0) {
  ($a, $b, $c, $d) = (shift(@m), shift(@m), shift(@m), shift(@m));
  push(@p, ("$a$b$c", $d));
}
@p = keys %{{map{$_ => 1} @p}};
```

Test this code **[here](http://ideone.com/hjWAd7)**.